# Can you please tell me how createview is working here ? I mean there is no link in action in form. the how clicking submit is not causing any error?

Tags: django

I am learining how to make a blog app using django. my doubt is createview is inserting data in the database but how does clciking on save button is not rasiing any error there is no link in actio= .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QgZa.png)

i have previously made some websites with falsk. so we should provide a link for action so that form data is sent on that link and  behind my code has some logic to insert taht recived data in databse. but here no link in action? so how does createview does this?

Comment: Need more information like the `views.py `and code for the form you have created.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to Django in particular – `<form action="">` (or indeed, a `<form>` without `action` set at all) has the browser submit the form to the current URL.

Quoting [the HTML spec, 4.10.21.3, Form Submission Algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#form-submission-algorithm):

> 12. Let `action` be the submitter element's *action*.
> 13. If `action` is the empty string, let action be the URL of the form document.

Then, CreateViews do different things depending on whether the action is GET or POST (which is similar to what you'd do in Flask).

Answer (score 0):

When you use **createView** in Django, the form submission and handling is done by View itself. Hence, You don't have to specify `action` attribute in the HTML form. (URL is associated with your createView) so, when you click on save button it does not raise an error.